# How to handle this CSS mouse hover issue?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following HTML structure?

```
<div id="content">

    <h3>some text</h3> <!--Another element having <h3> markup-->

    <div class="abc"> <!--This DIV does not have any id-->
        <div/>
        <h3>some text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and following `CSS` code

```
#content h3:hover, #content .abc:hover
{
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    background-image:url('/images/flag.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
}
```

**Problem I'm facing:**

When I hover mouse to `<h3>` under `<div id="content">` then it applies CSS as I expected. But when I hover mouse to `<div class="abc">` then it applies CSS for both `<div class="abc">` as well as `<h3>` element under `<div class="abc">`. So it's showing two images on mouse hover.

Can I control this behavior?

Means when I mouse hover to `<h3>` of `<div class="abc">` then it should show only one background image and not twice?

How can I achieve this? Using CSS only or Have to use jQuery?

Comment: Ok, first, you have a html error, you are closing abc div early: <div class="abc"> <!--This DIV does not have any id--> <div/><h3>some text</h3> that may be causing problems.

Comment: @DuverJaramillo, I have just shown one self closed `<div/>` as per my strucutre. Actually it's not a cause at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`#content > h3:hover, #myOutput > .abc:hover`

[Here's a codepen.](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/FHypl)

Your code uses the descendant selector (which is just a space), so you're telling the browser to apply your hover styles to any `h3` element that is a descendant of `#content`, which includes both `h3` elements. The code I have here uses the child combinator selector (`>`), which specifies only elements that are a direct descendant of the specified parent.

Confused? [Read this.](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: If I do as you suggested then hover get removed for <h3> element too as well as for .abc:hover too.

Comment: Yes. That's why I have written above content.

Comment: Then there's something else in effect that's not shown in your post.

Comment: See my updated post - there's a link to a live codepen. You have background hover set to a color that's very close to white, so I changed it to red for clarity.

Comment: You can use an infinite chain of child combinaters if you like, but you shouldn't. Use classes. Instead of .abc > h3, add a class to your h3 and then you can just use .abc-header. You're a dev, you would appreciate OOCSS. Google that and BEM, you'll love it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I done it using chain mechanism. like `#content > div > div > h3:hover`. Great friend.

Answer (score 2):

Change `#content h3:hover` to `#content > h3:hover`.

The problem is that also the second `<h3>` is a child of `#content` so the rule applies to it too. By using `>` you only select the `<h3>` which is a direct child of `#content`.

Comment: If I do as you suggested then hover get removed for <h3> element too

Comment: That's probably because you are using `#myOutput` instead of `#content`

Answer (score 0):

change your html into
"

```
<h3>some text</h3> 
<div class="abc"> sdfdsf </div>
    <h3>some text</h3>
```

"